# From the search result keep the chosen row and delete the other rows using Excel VBA or Excel formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a search result,they can search with the first name and last name,if one or more results came he need to select his name only and the remaining rows need to be deleted.I need to show that single student information into pivot table.how to do with this using vba or any excel formulas??I am having nearly 17 columns based on the date i need to show the students information in pivot table.

Comment: Please include the screenshot of table as well as efforts you made till now.

Comment: I am wondering,i am not able to add the screenshot here,so i may described it like in this way...sample input is like firstname,lastname,gmail,confirm gmail,telephone,address,etc are the columns.The result will come like this as in the first row vinela,chaganti,ch@gmail.com,ch@gmail.com,7777,hyderabd in the second row vinela,padiga,vp@gmail.com,vp@gmail.com,888,mumbai here need to select the second row and and delete the first row and need to show that second row information in pivot table. Note:the number of rows and selection of the name will change dynamically depending on the student names

Comment: This is very difficult to follow the question. Please take a look at: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Answer (score 0):

I have added the sample sheet. Now I am able to highlight the selected row, but I am not able to delete the remaining rows. From the sheet, I need to display the selected row that is "jill" information in the pivot table and delete the other rows. For highlighting the active row, I used this VBA code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Cells.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
Rows(Target.Row).Interior.Color = 12611584
End Sub
```

[image: sheet]